# Symfony2 Map Entity column to another class

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime

I'm new to symfony2. I'm having the following problem:

I have an Entity named Birthday (I've simplified the entity of course)

```
class Birthday{

   private $date;

   //@return \DateTime object
   public function getDate(){
     return $this->date;
   }

   public function __toString(){

      return $this->date->format('IM AWARE IS NOT A GOOD IDEA: the format should be taken from parameters.yml');


   }

}
```

I'd like to get an object of ANOTHER type instead of \DateTime. 
How could I do this?

I'd like to have a __toString method in the BirthDay Entity that would display the date in a format taken from parameters.yml.

Again, I'm aware it is absolutely not a good idea to pass a service container into an Entity since entities are POPO's .

I'm planning on doing a new Class that would take in account the date time format that I specify in parameters.yml

Answer (score 0):

add `format` property to the `Birthday` class and call it in `__toString` method..
example:
Entity:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->date->format($this->format);
}
```

Controller:

```
$format = $this->container->getParameter('FORMAT_FROM_PARAMETERS')

...
$birthday->setFormat($format);
...

print $birthday;
die;
```

Comment: That works but  what I want to avoid since I'd have to do that for each controller action. Thanks for your input

Comment: @兜甲児 Controller is just an example.. I think it would be better to create a factory class to create instances of `Birthday` class...